# How to decide the node and tiers in Appdynamics

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, monitoring, fastapi, appdynamics

I am new to AppDynamics to I am confused how to decide about node and tiers

My application is using :

```
Angular JS and TypeScript : Frontend

fastapi : Backend

AWS EKS cluster and S3 bucket and CloudFront : for frontend and backend deployment
```

I am also using some Data-Management-Platform APIs and SNOW APIs

I can`t decide  how many nodes do I need in this application and how to decide that this part should be a node and tier

Answer (score 1):

Put simply: A Node is an instance of an application, a Tier is a collection of instances which have the same functionality.

"Angular JS and TypeScript : Frontend" - You would need Browser Real User Monitoring (BRUM) in order to monitor the front end. This is not organised into Tiers and Nodes, but rather page views and browser sessions.

"fastapi : Backend" - Assuming a set of Nodes with the same functionality, here you may want to have a 'fastapi' Tier which contains a number of Nodes. So one might be Tier = 'fastapi', Node = 'fastapi-1' and another might be Tier = 'fastapi', Node = 'fastapi-2'. If there are different types of Node (different functionality) these should be arrange into different Tiers (e.g. "Authentication", or "Reporting")

"AWS EKS cluster and S3 bucket and CloudFront : for frontend and backend deployment" - Here you should likely be using the Cluster Agent which again uses different concepts based on Kubernetes architecture

Docs:

- https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.9/en/end-user-monitoring/browser-monitoring
- https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.9/en/application-monitoring/tiers-and-nodes
- https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.9/en/infrastructure-visibility/monitor-kubernetes-with-the-cluster-agent